# Password-protect hosted web app

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to password-protect a clone of the [Google Analytics Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) website hosted on appspot.com and built in Node.js and Python. [The github project for which is here.](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools)
Appspot doesn't let you run PHP on Python-based sites so PHP isn't an option for password-protecting the site. Is there another way I can password protect a web project like this?

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday (**edit**: yes, and from [a different account](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32976062/3001761))? You now have included the question, at least, but it's still much too broad for SO.

Comment: Why would you think "PHP" is a way to password protect a site? It's a way of writing a site, which may or may not have password protection; you would just write your node or Python app in the same way.

Comment: - Jon, thanks for the comment. I am very new to StackOverflow and so am not yet familiar with the posting etiquette.  -Daniel, thanks for the suggestions.  I will look into password protecting nodes and/or Python apps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the app.yaml configuration file to require "login: admin" on all handlers, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status).